# How does one make a jquery conditional with two events?

Tags: jquery

I've never written an if statement before.

I want the two slideframe divs to move when I click but only if the variable `navi` is not equal to zero, and then to set `navi` to 1 after the divs have moved:

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
    $("#one").click(function(){
        if (navi !=0) {
           $(".slideframe").animate({opacity: "0.1", left: "-=960"}, 1200)
           $(".slideframe1").animate({ left: "-=960"}, 1200)
           navi = 1 
        }
    }); 
});
```

This just breaks the working jquery, but the best result I have got is for *one* div to slide but never *two*.

What am I doing wrong?

So thanks to Patrik this makes one of the divs move but not the first one! (i.e not .slideframe) .. but they both move if i dont put the if statement in...

```
<script>
var navi = "0";
</script>


<script>
$(document).ready(function(){   
    $("#one").click(function(){
        if (navi !=0)
    $(".slideframe").animate({opacity: "0.1", left: "-=960"}, 1200);
    $(".slideframe1").animate({ left: "-=960"}, 1200);
    navi = 1; 
    }); 
});
</script>
```

Comment: To @jeffamaphone (the 2nd person to edit the post): you know that there are people whose first language is not English? Maybe you could choose better wording for commenting your edits next time...

Comment: Define navi like `var navi = 0;` not `= "0";`.

Comment: @Cipi - Actually, in javascript `0 == "0"` returns `true`. Using `0 === "0"` does a more expected comparison and would return `false`.

Comment: Actualy `var navi = 1;`.

Comment: @patric: I meant to write 1 not 0. xD I'm sleepy... =)

Answer (score 1):

You are missing semicolons at the end of your statements.

This should do:

```
$(".slideframe").animate({opacity: "0.1", left: "-=960"}, 1200);
$(".slideframe1").animate({ left: "-=960"}, 1200);
navi = 1;
```

Comment: Semicolons are optional in javascript (although formally recommended).

Comment: :-( fraid not ... thanks though .. if i enclose the if in {} then nothing works if  leave out the {} (as below) only one div will move..

<script>
var navi = "0";
</script>



<script>
$(document).ready(function(){ 
 $("#one").click(function(){
  if (navi !=0)
 $(".slideframe").animate({opacity: "0.1", left: "-=960"}, 1200);
 $(".slideframe1").animate({ left: "-=960"}, 1200);
 navi = 1; 
 }); 
});
</script>

Comment: @David: you're right... that's the problem of using too many languages... mixing things together in your head :P

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you should set `navi` to 1 in a callback:

```
if (navi !=0) {
  $(".slideframe").animate({opacity: "0.1", left: "-=960"}, 1200)
  $(".slideframe1").animate({ left: "-=960"}, 1200, function() {
    navi = 1;
  });
}
```

This way navi will be '1' when the animation is complete.

The reason why your code breaks is likely a racing condition. If you want your elements to move only once when the user clicks, use the `.one` function in jQuery instead.

Comment: yes the idea is to make the navi 1 after the animation is complete, thanks .. but still not working :-(

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a few semicolons after your statements but as long as they are on different lines, Javascript shouldn't care. What might be going on is your .slideframes are statically positioned (that's the default value) and left has no effect on statically positioned elements. Try changing it to marginLeft or some other attribute that will certainly have an effect so you can isolate whether it's a CSS problem or a Javascript one.

Also just putting navi = 1 after your animate statements will cause it to be changed right after the animates are called. If you want navi changed after they are done animating, you need to use the callback that David posted.

Comment: No everything works fine before i added the if statement, so :

this works fine: <script>
$(document).ready(function(){ 
 $("#one").click(function(){
 $(".slideframe").animate({opacity: "0.1", left: "-=960"}, 1200);
 $(".slideframe1").animate({ left: "-=960"}, 1200);
 }); 
});
</script>

Comment: Oh and even i remove the navi = 1 .. i cna only ever get one div to move.... so strange!

Answer (score 0):

How and where is `navi` defined? Did you write `var navi = 1;` somewhere? Make sure you did.

Try to put `opacity` and `left` in strings:

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
    $("#one").click(function(){
        if (navi != 0) {
           $(".slideframe").animate({"opacity": "0.1", "left": "-=960"}, 1200);
           $(".slideframe1").animate({ "left": "-=960"}, 1200);
           navi = 1; 
        }
    }); 
});
```

Also, your divs must have `position: absolute` set so they move when you change left...

EDIT:
`navi` must be 1 for if to execute.

Comment: <script>
var navi = "0";
</script>

Answer (score 0):

Yes it was this:

```
<script>
var navi = 0;
</script>
```

not

```
<script>
var navi = "0";
</script>
```

Thank you!

```
<script>
var navi = 0;
</script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){   
    $("#one").click(function(){
                if (navi !=1){
    $(".slideframe").animate({opacity: "0.1", left: "-=960"}, 1200);
    $(".slideframe1").animate({ left: "-=960"}, 1200,function() {
    navi = 1;
  }); }
    }); 
});
</script>
```